# Extending Models and Seeding Tables with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models

I'm trying to figure what seeding has to do with whether or not I extend a model to the base model which extends eloquent or not because when I turn the user model into extending eloquent and run a seed file it works but I keep it the way it is then it puts empty values for all the fillable fields.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to possibly fix it?

**User Model**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait, SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'avatar', 'role_id', 'status_id', 'email_address', 'password'];

    protected static $rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'avatar' => 'required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'role_id' => 'required',
        'status_id' => 'required'
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    /**
     * Get the user's full name by concatenating the first and last names
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```

**Base Model**

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $errors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            return $model->validate();
        });
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($this->getAttributes(), static::$rules);

        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            $this->errors = $validation->messages();

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

**UsersTableSeeder**

```
<?php

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {    
        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'First',
            'last_name' => 'Last',
            'username' => 'myusername',
            'email_address' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'avatar' => 'Myava',
            'password' => Hash::make('changeme'),
            'role_id' => 4,
            'status_id' => 1
        ]);

        //create instanances for each fake user
        $faker = Faker::create();

        $roleIds = UserRole::lists('id');
        $statusIds = UserStatus::lists('id');

        foreach(range(1, 20) as $index)
        {
            User::create([
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'username' => $faker->username,
                'email_address' => $faker->freeEmail,
                'avatar' => $faker->lexify('????????'),
                'password' => Hash::make($faker->word),
                'role_id' => $faker->randomElement($roleIds),
                'status_id' => $faker->randomElement($statusIds)
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructors are incompatible with Eloquent's.

Get rid of them, since they don't do anything, or make compatible:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to put that in the User model AND BaseModel?

Comment: You should delete those constructors, unless you will be adding dependencies, which I doubt. And yes, if you want the constructors, then both should look this way. But again, in this form they are redundant